# What is the technical term for highlighting a record in an application's list view?

Tags: maximo

Maximo 7.6.1.1:

In the List View of an application, I can click a record to highlight it.

- The record's background turns light-blue.
- I can only highlight a single record.
- Highlighting is not to be confused with [selecting records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLkj5.png) via checkboxes. Nor is it to be confused with clicking the WONUM hyperlink (opening the record).

[image]

<sup>*On a side note: I can also perform [custom actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37lbv.png) on the highlighted record.*</sup>

---

**Question:**

I discovered this business of highlighting records in the list view by accident. I just made up the term "highlighting".

What is the correct technical term for this functionality?

- I'd like to find out more about it, but when I google things like `maximo "list view" highlight` I don't see any relevant results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can observe this behaviour in any table. While that highlighted record is often referred to as the "selected" record, you are correct that it should not be confused with being selected via checkboxes. The highlighted record is the "current" record or the "active" record in the table. The current record in one table may determine which records are shown in another table. For example, in Database Configurations, the selected Index drives which columns are shown in the table below.

To a Maximo developer, the current record in a table is the current Mbo in an MboSet.